# Linear Independence of Vectors that are a Linear Combination of other Linearly Independent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose v1,v2,v3 are linearly independent vectors in a vector space V and let

w1 = v1 + av2 ,      w2 = v2 + av3,        w3 = v3 + av1

for some a ∈ R. For what values of a are the vectors w1, w2 and w3 linearly independent?

I got a = (-x1v1 - x2v2 - x3v3)/(x3v1 + x1v2 + x2v3 ) for x1, x2, x3 and arbitrary constants, I just want to know if this is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_1w_1+c_2w_2+c_3w_3=0$, so $c_1(v_1+av_2)+c_2(v_2+av_3)+c_3(v_3+av_1)=0$.

Then $(c_1+ac_3)v_1+(c_2+ac_1)v_2+(c_3+ac_2)v_3=0$, so

$c_1+ac_3=0,\;\;c_2+ac_1=0,\;\;c_3+ac_2=0$ since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.

Now find for which values of $a$ we can conclude that $c_1=0, c_2=0, c_3=0$.